# Creating 1D vectors over 3D tensors in pytorch

Tags: matrix, pytorch

I have the following tensor with dimensions `(2, 3, 2, 2)` where the dimensions represent `(batch_size, channels, height, width)`:

```
tensor([[[[ 1.,  2.],
          [ 3.,  4.]],

         [[ 5.,  6.],
          [ 7.,  8.]],

         [[ 9., 10.],
          [11., 12.]]],


        [[[13., 14.],
          [15., 16.]],

         [[17., 18.],
          [19., 20.]],

         [[21., 22.],
          [23., 24.]]]])
```

I would like to convert this into the following tensor with dimensions `(8, 3)`:

```
tensor([[ 1,  5,  9],
        [ 2,  6, 10],
        [ 3,  7, 11],
        [ 4,  8, 12],
        [13, 17, 21],
        [14, 18, 22],
        [15, 19, 23],
        [16, 20, 24]])
```

Essentially I would like to create 1D vector over the elements of the matrices. I have tried many operations such as flatten and reshape, but I cannot figure out how to achieve this reshaping.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```py
import torch

x = torch.Tensor(
   [
    [
    [[1,2],[3,4]],
    [[5,6],[7,8]],
    [[9,10],[11,12]]],
    [
    [[13,14],[15,16]],
    [[17,18],[19,20]],
    [[21,22],[23,24]]]
   ]  
)

result = x.swapaxes(0, 1).reshape(3, -1).T

print(result)
# > tensor([[ 1.,  5.,  9.],
# >         [ 2.,  6., 10.],
# >         [ 3.,  7., 11.],
# >         [ 4.,  8., 12.],
# >         [13., 17., 21.],
# >         [14., 18., 22.],
# >         [15., 19., 23.],
# >         [16., 20., 24.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with an axes permutation and a flattening the resulting tensor:

1. swap `axis=1` (of size `3`) with the last one: `axis=-1`, using [`torch.permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.permute.html#torch.Tensor.permute) ([`torch.swapaxes`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.swapaxes.html) is an alias),
2. flatten everything but the last axis *i.e.* from `axis=0` to `axis=-2` using [`torch.flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html).

This looks like:

```
>>> x.transpose(1, -1).flatten(0, -2)
tensor([[ 1.,  5.,  9.],
        [ 3.,  7., 11.],
        [ 2.,  6., 10.],
        [ 4.,  8., 12.],
        [13., 17., 21.],
        [15., 19., 23.],
        [14., 18., 22.],
        [16., 20., 24.]])
```